# Implementing user search on username and/or name on mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm looking to implement a user search on my MongoDB database with Mongoose, it has a table of users with these fields:

- name (full name not unique)
- username (unique)
- there are other fields like email, dateCreated, etc. of course

I know how to do a search on or the other (only match username or only match name), but is it possible to implement search by both fields (match username or name)

E.g.

```
|    Users     | Username |
|--------------|----------|
| Will Riker   | riker01  |
| Bill Reilly  | riker02  |
| Daniel Riker | dan001   |
| James dean   | dean001  |
```

And if I query on `riker`, it would return `riker01`, `riker 02` and `dan001`

Comment: Check this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) with [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) in this way:

```
var word = "riker"
yourModel.find({
  "$or": [
    {
      "user": {
        "$regex": word,
        "$options": "i"
      },
      
    },
    {
      "username": {
        "$regex": word,
        "$options": "i"
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Note how `$options: "i"` is neccessary to be case sensitive.

You can check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8cBm4zkWie5)

Answer (score 2):

You can use index [$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) in mongo. What you have to do is just add text parameter in your model fields you are going to search:

```
name: {
  type: String,
  text: true
},
username: {
  type: String,
  text: true
}
```

Run this to synchronize your index with your collection
`db.collection.syncIndexes();`

```
db.users.find({
  $text: {$search: searchkey}
})
```